# extend ArrayDeque correctly

Tags: java, inheritance, queue

I am having trouble extending `ArrayDeque`. My problem can be distilled (mcve?) down to the following:

My queue will take only key-value pair objects.

```
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;

public class TicketsQueue<E> extends ArrayDeque<E> {

    transient ArrayDeque<SimpleEntry<String, String>> tickets = new ArrayDeque<SimpleEntry<String, String>>();

    public boolean offer(String category, String ticketId) {
        return tickets.offer(new SimpleEntry<String, String>(category, ticketId));
    }
}
```

I also have a custom `poll()` method, but I do not believe that is relevant to my problem here. Most other things that `ArrayDeque` has I intent to use as-is.

I then try to use my `TicketsQueue` like so:

```
public class TicketsQueueTest {

    @Test
    public void testTixQueue() {
        TicketsQueue<SimpleEntry<String, String>> tixQueue = new TicketsQueue<SimpleEntry<String, String>>();
        tixQueue.offer("foo", "bar");
        Assert.assertFalse("It's empty!", tixQueue.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

This fails. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Why do you need to use inheritance?

Comment: @Steephen The other things that `ArrayDeque` has (like `isEmpty()`, `clear()`, `clone()`, possibly others) I intend to use as-is.

Comment: @You already initialized tickets  using association. I didn't get the reason why do you need inheritance as well as associaition?

Comment: @Steephen I guess I do not understand the distinction between those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading about association, thanx to Steephen, I came up with following fix:

```
public class TicketsQueue<E> extends ArrayDeque<E> {

    public boolean offer(String category, String ticketId) {
        return offer((E) new SimpleEntry<String, String>(category, ticketId));
    }
}
```

This makes my `TicketsQueueTest` pass.

Answer (score 0):

I have   minimized the implementation as follows. I hope that may resolve your issue.

```
public class TicketsQueue{

       transient ArrayDeque<SimpleEntry<String, String>> tickets = new ArrayDeque<SimpleEntry<String, String>>();

       public boolean offer(String category, String ticketId) {
            return tickets.offer(new SimpleEntry<String, String>(category, ticketId));
        }   

        public static void main(String args[]) {                
            TicketsQueue tixQueue = new TicketsQueue();
            tixQueue.offer("foo", "bar");
            assert(tixQueue.tickets.isEmpty());         
        }
}
```